# Rails I got error that says undefined local variable or method `script' for main:Object (NameError) when I work rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## directory

-app┣ script─collect.rb

### command

```
     rails runner script/collect.rb
    Running via Spring preloader in process 2771
    /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `script' for main:Object (NameError)
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `eval'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `runner'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/RubymineProjects/share-tan/vendor/bundl/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
     from /Users/nishidaryu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
     from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

##code

```
class Collect
  def quizlet
   @response=[]
   response = Unirest.get "https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/search/sets/?client_id=7JH38T27zM&whitespace=1",
                       parameters:{ whitespace: true,q: "Duo3.0",term:100,sort:"most_studied"}
   res=response.body

  quizlet_ids=[]
   res["sets"].each do|res|
    quizlet_ids<<res["id"]
  end


   quizlet_words = Unirest.get "https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/sets/?client_id=7JH38T27zM&whitespace=1",
                            parameters:{ whitespace: true,set_ids:"#{quizlet_ids}"}

   quizlet_words.body.each do|words|
    words["terms"].each do|word|
    response=word
    response["quizlet_id"]=words["id"]
    response["check_id"]=word["id"]
    response["question_language"]= words["lang_terms"]
    response["answer_language"]  = words["lang_definitions"]
    @response<<response
    @response.each do|response|
      quizlet_save(response[:quizlet_id],response[:check_id],response[:term],response[:definition],response[:question_language],response[:answer_language])
     end
    end
   end
 end

 def quizlet_save(quizlet_id,check_id,question,answer,question_language,answer_language)
unless Word.find_by(check_id:check_id)&&Word.find_by(quizlet_id:quizlet_id)
  Word.create(quizlet_id:quizlet_id,check_id:check_id,title:"Quizlet",question:question,answer:answer,user_id:1,tag_list:"English,Duo3.0,Vocabulary",
              question_language:question_language,answer_language:answer_language)
end
word=Word.find_by(check_id:check_id)
unless word == nil
  checking_word=Word.find_by(quizlet_id:quizlet_id)
     group=Group.find_by(id: checking_word.group_id)
      if group==nil
    created_group=Group.new(user_id:1,title:"Quizlet",explanation:"Quizlet Duo3.0")
    created_group=created_group.save(validate: false)&&created_group
    word.update_attribute(:group_id,created_group.id)
    else
    word.update_attribute(:group_id,group.id)
    end
   end
 end
```

end

### environment

- ruby 2.3
- rails 4.2.8

I think there is no miss but error occurs and in spite of my effort, I can't find any solution.
I've never used rails runner so I don't know about that in details.

Comment: So, do you run `rails runner` from the root application folder, right?

Comment: Yes,I run `rails runner` from the root application folder.

Comment: could you provide a full path to your script?

Comment: share-tan/app/script/collect.rb

Comment: did you run it from the `share-tan` folder or `share-tan/app` folder?

Comment: From the share-tan folder not share-tan/app

Comment: so strange error, try to put your file into the `app/lib` folder and repeat command with new folder

Comment: Yeah,I thought so,and I did like that. then I got `Running via Spring preloader in process 44166` is that OK? I cannot check that whether right or not,because of it needs too much time to finish the processing.

Comment: Yep, that's OK, I suppose

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move your file into the `lib` folder. And If you want to see some output, you can simply paste a line `puts 'code is running'` into your `collect.rb` file to test that code is actually running. Hope it will help!